# Pandoc convention to follow to write frontmatter, body & backmatter of a book in markdown

Tags: pdftex, pandoc

I am writing a book in markdown & use pandoc to convert the book to pdf (pandoc internally uses `pdflatex`/`xelatex`/`lualatex`) & epub

Is there a way to specify in the markdown document that a given section (`# Preface`) belongs to `frontmatter` & `# Appendix` belongs to the `backmatter`?

Please note that I want to write frontmatter, backmatter & mainbody all in markdown

PS: In the documentation, I see an option for [epub](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#the-epubtype-attribute), but not for pdf

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'm not shure if pure markdown is on topic here ...

Comment: Thanks :) Even I am not sure where to post the question as to whether it belongs to SO/here. Since the issue is w.r.t pandoc in combination with pdf (that uses TeX internally for pdf generation), I posted it here

Comment: Also, the answer to this question might not be pure markdown. Pandoc allows Latex to be embedded to make certain things happen when it comes to pdf generation. I'm not sure if the solution requires the latex commands incombination with markdown

Comment: In LaTeX you can use `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter`. How to do that with markdown I can not tell you ...

Comment: Thanks. I am already aware of that. I am looking at the mechanism of telling pandoc to do that internally

Comment: looking for* the mechanism

Comment: You can include raw LaTeX commands in markdown so that they are unchanged in a  latex export. The main problem is add `\frontmatter` properly at the very beginning of the document environment, but this can be solved using a custom template.